# Using vue.use in a library own

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using the vue-sfc-rollup lib to create a lib for Vue, so far it's ok, my lib is working, and I can use it in other projects, however, a doubt has arisen.

In which file could I add in my lib the use of bootstrap? to understand better I'm putting below the structure that the SFC generated for me..

[image]

The file entry.js

```
// iife/cjs usage extends esm default export - so import it all
import plugin, * as components from '@/entry.esm';

// Attach named exports directly to plugin. IIFE/CJS will
// only expose one global var, with component exports exposed as properties of
// that global var (eg. plugin.component)
Object.entries(components).forEach(([componentName, component]) => {
  if (componentName !== 'default') {
    plugin[componentName] = component;
  }
});

export default plugin;
```

the file entry.esm.js

```
// Import vue components
import * as components from '@/lib-components/index';

// install function executed by Vue.use()
const install = function installZicketVueCheckout(Vue) {
  Object.entries(components).forEach(([componentName, component]) => {
    Vue.component(componentName, component);
  });  
};

// Create module definition for Vue.use()
export default install;

// To allow individual component use, export components
// each can be registered via Vue.component()
export * from '@/lib-components/index';
```

Comment: What do you mean by VueUse and bootstrap?

Comment: I mean where can I include bootstrap in a lib (which is in my case).
Generally, when we create any project in vue, we use Vue.use() to import the libs, in my example, I'm making the lib, and I wanted to know if I could put the bootstrap in it, so when the person installs my lib my component will already be formatted.

Comment: Vue.use() is used to install [plugins](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) not libraries. Bootstrap is a library, not a plugin so it doesn't need to be installed through Vue.use(). You use a package manager like npm or yarn for libraries.

Comment: Look at [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjs) to bundle bootstrap with your library

Comment: I dont found a example using bootstrap, do you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, no - I've never used it myself but it should do the trick since it is used to bundle dependencies into the final library